# The selected file is not a valid solution file

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I have finished some days ago a format on my computer. After i have tried to open some of my solutions files the error that is mentioned in the tile is shown. (Note: Some of my solutions file can be opened if that is of any help. Also i have downloaded this update https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39305).
I have read some other posts that mention that some updates might have been done to visual studio before the format that i don;t have now but i can't remember which i have donw to be honest. Is there any way to open these solution files?

EDIT:

Another files show these

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00
# Visual Studio 2012
Project("{E24C65DC-7377-472B-9ABA-BC803B73C61A}") = "WebSite1", "http://localhost/WebSite1", "{23FFA0C5-7FFE-4F49-A3C8-E8D407B61DB8}"
    ProjectSection(WebsiteProperties) = preProject
        UseIISExpress = "false"
        TargetFrameworkMoniker = ".NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.VirtualPath = "/WebSite1"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.PhysicalPath = "..\..\..\..\..\..\inetpub\wwwroot\WebSite1\"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.TargetPath = "PrecompiledWeb\WebSite1\"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.Updateable = "true"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.ForceOverwrite = "true"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.FixedNames = "false"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.Debug = "True"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.VirtualPath = "/WebSite1"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.PhysicalPath = "..\..\..\..\..\..\inetpub\wwwroot\WebSite1\"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.TargetPath = "PrecompiledWeb\WebSite1\"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.Updateable = "true"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.ForceOverwrite = "true"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.FixedNames = "false"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.Debug = "False"
        SlnRelativePath = "..\..\..\..\..\..\inetpub\wwwroot\WebSite1\"
    EndProjectSection
EndProject
Global
    GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
        Debug|Any CPU = Debug|Any CPU
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution
        {23FFA0C5-7FFE-4F49-A3C8-E8D407B61DB8}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {23FFA0C5-7FFE-4F49-A3C8-E8D407B61DB8}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(SolutionProperties) = preSolution
        HideSolutionNode = FALSE
    EndGlobalSection
EndGlobal
```

Any ideas why it cannot be opened?

Comment: Solution files are XML-ish plain text files. Perhaps it is actually corrupted. I would inspect it with a text editor. If you post it here, the error might be more clear.

Comment: Just to be perfectly clear it is a .sln file. If i open it with visual studio from inside another project as an existing file it is full of zeros.

Comment: Well then, it seems as if the error you are getting is correct, it is corrupt.

Comment: Thank you, if you can assist with the above edit too it would be great.

Comment: What do you mean full of zeros. The file you posted has no zeros

Comment: The other file that i have checked before this had zeros.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You tagged your question with Visual Studio 2012. Your example solution file is in Visual Studio 2013 format. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#History for the history of version numbers

You should open it with Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: Hello. Thanks a lot for your answer and sorry for my big delay. When i try to open it, it says: Unable to open the Web site 'http://localhost/WebSite1'.  The Web site 'http://localhost/WebSite1' does not exist. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

For me this solution worked perfect:

Create new project in visual studio(new project name should be same as main projct name) and delete any default created project in new solution. now go to new project location and copy .sln file. go to main project location and delete .sln file and paste copied .sln file and open, than rebiuld solution again.

Note: if faced any erorr about project manifest you can edit .csproj(by notepad) and delete any tag related to manifet and save. again reload solution.

For me this worked.